# Can visibility of Files related to sObject be restricted for certain users that have edit access to that object

Tags: files, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

We have Internal Financial Request object and Files related list. Let's assume there is two users `user1` and `user2` with edit access to a particular record of IFR.

If `user1` uploads file related to this record, `user2` will be able to see this file. Is there a way to restrict visibility of that file for `user2` without restricting his access to the record itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished if `user1` [makes the file private on the record](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_make_private_on_record.htm&type=5):

> The File Privacy on Records option lets you control the visibility of
> a file when it’s attached to a record. If you don’t see the File
> Privacy on Records option when you edit a file’s details, ask your
> admin to add it. Only admins and file owners can change the value of
> File Privacy on Records.

Comment: Thank you, it helped!